# Copy website folder and contents to Apache web server

Tags: html, apache, webserver

I just started setting up Apache web server to try and test a website I am building. After installing LAMP (I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, if that's important), I copied a folder of HTML and CSS code that I had to test. Here is the folder's contents:

```
Main folder: testsite  
Subfolders: articles, images, CSS, HTML, scripts   
Contents:  
    articles -> .docx files  
    images   -> .png files  
    CSS      -> .css files  
    HTML     -> .html files  
    scripts  -> .py files, but one .html file too
```

When I went to test the Apache web server, it gave a 404 not found. I'm absolutely clueless as to what could be the answer. I tried renaming the `maincode.html` file that I had to `index.html` and putting it in the `testsite` folder, but it didn't change anything. Is there anything I need to do to fix this?

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0ibT.png) of the 404 Not Found page, with the Developer Console open (in Chrome)

I'm not sure what other information I need to provide, but I'll gladly give any info you need.

Comment: after installing LAMP, before you copied your files, were you able to browse to the 'It Works!' page that Apache hosts by default?

Comment: yes, I was able to do that

Comment: I would also verify that the copied files have the correct file permissions on them (so Apache can access them) see https://askubuntu.com/questions/386928/default-permissions-for-var-www

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your testsite's conf file has the `DocumentRoot` property set to the path to your testsite folder. The conf file is probably */etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf*.

Comment: I did this as well as created a ServerAlias with the domain name, and restarted Apache. Now it gives a DNS error in Chrome. But progress has been made! Thank you!